# How to make a div full screen and expand with its content as it overflows

Tags: html, css, height

I have a single root div that contains all the page content. My goal is:

- when the content does not overflow at the bottom, to make the div take 100% of the height.
- when the content does overflow at the bottom, I want the div to expand so that it encapsulates all the content.

I tried a lot of combinations with `height` and `min-height` but I struggle to make it.
What I have currently is this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html, body, #root {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #root {
    background: yellow;
  }  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when you scroll to see the content that overflows, the background is gone, while I want it to grow with the content.
How can I do this?

Comment: do you want the background to follow? Meaning background keep same size (100% height) and follow the scroll? Or do you want the background to expand with the size of your content?

Comment: I want the background to expand with the size of the content. It should be at least the size of the screen when the content is smaller than the screen, and effectively grow in height as the content grows.

Comment: check the 2 answers below, that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `height: 100%;` with `min-height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 0):

The unit `vh` expresses a percentage of the viewport height. So you can make the main `div` at least fill the window vertically like this:

```css
  body, #root {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #root {
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```